# Using maven repositories in multi module gradle setup

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project with multiple modules.

Module A has a dependency on aar present in maven remote repository, which is specified in build.gradle as below

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Module B has a dependency on another aar, which is specified in its own build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public' }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8+'
}
```

When I compile the project, I get the following error.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':-app:'.
  > Could not find any matches for com.localytics.android:library:3.8+ as no versions of com.localytics.android:library are available.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/localytics/android/library/maven-metadata.xml
     https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/localytics/android/library/
```

Looks like gradle picks up the url only from Module A.

If I specify the url in top level build.gradle, then it works properly. But I don't want to specify a module level dependency at the top level.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public' }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to specify maven repositories in multiple modules ?

Comment: The `allprojects` is for multiple modules.

Comment: Your description suggests that it's *not* really a module level dependency.  The library is used by multiple modules, therefore it could very much be configured at a higher level to be used by all of them.  Do you have a particular reason why you don't want to use allprojects like this?  Do you have an alternative in mind that you are having problems implementing?

Comment: @DougStevenson  The dependencies are at the module level only and not used by other modules. I am building a library and an application in my project, and I want all dependencies and the corresponding maven url's to be present in the module's build.gradle and not in the higher level build.gradle as is the case with allprojects.  If gradle doesn't allow this, then I have to manually download the jar for one of the dependency and copy into the libs folder.

Comment: What's the harm, in your mind, of having a repository live in allprojects, even if it isn't explicitly used in the subprojects?  What you're describing is still exactly the case for allprojects.  If there is really a problem adding a repository to a module that doesn't need it (tell me what the problem is!) you can have a repositories block in each module if that helps.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I have already tried repositories block in each module and it didn't work. Gradle picked the repositories block only from Module A and not from Module B.  As I am building a library (aar) from a module, I am not sure how the transitive dependencies will work on other apps that will include my library, if the maven url is not specified inside the library's build.gradle